# Error when trying to build a Global Keyboard Hook in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm developing a code to get keyboard input in KeyPress and KeyRelease events, but when i run the program nothing happens, what is wrong with my code? And how to get the pressed key value?

```
void hook()
{
    forever
    {
        XEvent event;
        Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case KeyPress:
            qDebug() << "keypress";
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            qDebug() << "keyrelease";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [keyboard X11 events](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html). You will get them only from some X11 windows, if that window has set some of `KeyPressMask` or `KeyReleaseMask` bits in its [event mask](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/event-and-do-not-propagate.html). And that window should be [created](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/create.html) `InputOnly` or `InputOutput`

You are apparently using Qt (which is a good idea). Then, stick to Qt [key](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) events.

(if you want to catch all X11 key events, use the root window of the display. But then you are interfering with your window manager, which is a bad idea; learn more about [ICCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICCCM) and [EWMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints))

Also, run `xev` -in a terminal- to understand more about X11 events