# Using Bar code scanner with WX python app

Tags: wxpython, barcode-scanner

This is a very general question and i am Hoping people can point me to the right documentation.

Basically I would like to use a Physical Bar code scanner to help with entries for my Wx python Data entry App I am creating for my Company.
I am hoping for a Bar Code scanner with a carriage return enabled so I can use it to scan the bar codes on the work order to save time. I Do not know how to integrate it to python .
Any info/examples would be amazing.

[MyApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPTFE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be nothing particularly difficult.
Customization, such as adding a carriage return code at the end of the barcode notification, is done by having the scanner read the configuration barcode.

You want to keep the input focus on the correct field (text box?).

Notifications from the scanner are made as if a human had entered data from the keyboard.

Comment: So if what i understand is right. All I need to do i just install a bar code scanner and just select my text box-> scan and the string should pop up in my text field?
I dont need any special I/O reader module?

Comment: It will be correct with your understanding. If the scanner hardware is set to keyboard input emulation mode, no additional modules are required.

Comment: Follow up Question, What if i need the scanner to tab trough to the next text box after scanning. Is this also a default option?

Comment: Here's another article I answered earlier. [How do I distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53623783/9014308) Instead of a carriage return, you could specify TAB as the code to signal the end of the barcode notification. It is also specified in the settings barcode.