# Using barcode scanner to insert to datagridview automatically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox, barcode-scanner

My vb.net code is working perfectly, when I scan the barcode it interpret perfectly, but I must press enter to execute

*Private Sub txtScan_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtScan.KeyDown*

i.e. I must press enter to insert into datagridview.
I want the code to insert to data into datagridview automatically after scanning into textbox.

Kindly help

Comment: You can normally configure the scanner to set whether it sends an 'enter' after a scan.  Check the scanner settings as that's how we handle this.

Comment: You should be able to work out if it is a manually typed or scanned number by timing the duration between the first key press and the last (I’m assuming a fixed length barcode). When you reach the last, and if the last is below a time threshold then trigger an enter.

Comment: You can apply the ideas in this article. [How do I distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53573584/9014308)