# How to Check if User input is from Barcode Scanner or Keyboard? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, barcode, barcode-scanner, keyboard-events

I have input box.
This input box may have a value as a barcode scanner or user input.
But, key event from barcode scanner or user input have same keypress Events.
I want to distinguish between these Key Event.
Is there a way to tell where the Event is coming from in JavaScript?

Thanks.

I tried to detect it as an event, but I couldn't find any difference.

Comment: No, there is nothing built-in that lets you identify the input. A barcode scanner acts like a keyboard. You _could_ look at the timing of the individual keystrokes, but that'll be complicated and possibly inaccurate

Comment: Is it a duplicate here? [How do I distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53573584/9014308)